# Elastisearch query to return only match filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying the below query using console

```
GET logstash-2021*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "msg": "task success"
          }
        },
        {
"terms": {
      "messageID": ["198211953070","198210808067"]
    }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

ES is returning all documents for the above messageID which contain `msg` other than `task success` like `task received` etc. What can be changed if only the above `task success` logs are needed to be returned and no other type of `msg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [match phrase query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html)

```
{
  "match_phrase": {
    "msg": "task success"
  }
}
```